# sed command removing #

Tags: sed

I am using below sed command, but if `MacAddressPasswordeRegisteryValue` is `WElcome12#` then its producing `WElcome12` and removing `#`. Any way to avoid it?

```
sed -i "s#^mac.address.sftp.user.password=.*#mac.address.sftp.user.password=${MacAddressPasswordeRegisteryValue#*=}#" $APP_CONFIG_FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the password may contain any character, then no delimiter that you use for the `sed` expression is safe to use.  If you had, for example, `s/.../.../` and the password contained `/`, you would have the same issue again.

Therefore, don't use `sed` here.  Instead,

```
awk -v pw="$MacAddressPasswordeRegisteryValue" \
    'BEGIN { OFS=FS="=" }
    $1 == "mac.address.sftp.user.password" { print $1, pw; next } 1' \
    "$APP_CONFIG_FILE" >"$APP_CONFIG_FILE"-new
```

This would transform

```
mac.address.sftp.user.password=something old
```

into

```
mac.address.sftp.user.password=hello world !#$/
```

given that `$MacAddressPasswordeRegisteryValue` was the string `hello world !#$/`.  Other lines would be passed through unmodified to the new file `"$APP_CONFIG_FILE"-new`.

Comment: Maybe parameter expansion of the variable to escape #? `sed “s#foo#${var//#\\#}#”`

Comment: @JeffSchaller Consider the password `hello\#`.

Comment: `sed` is perfectly fine here as long as the variable is pre-processed (also via `sed` @JeffSchaller).